# Formula to display dates of every Friday and Sunday in a year in xl sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Formula to display `Dates` of every Friday's and Sunday's in a year as `list` in xl sheet? Could someone please advise ?

Comment: Today(), weekday(), and adding 7 may get you somewhere. Do show what you have tried as "I already tried that" wastes effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=TEXT(DATE($A$1,1,1)-MOD(WEEKDAY(DATE($A$1,1,1)),{5,7})+1+7*ROWS($1:1),"yyyy-mm-dd ddd")`

Where `A1` holds the year.
This spills the result of Friday (`5`) and Sunday (`7`) next to each other (Office 365). Copy down.